# How to count the number of possible combinations to fill an arrray of K boxes and S symbols

Tags: python, arrays, combinations

I want to know the number of possible combinations to fill an array that contains 25 boxes (array 5*5) which can be fill with 2 symbols (0 or 1). How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Do you want to know the number of 5 symbol sequences containing the symbols 0 and 1? Do you want to know the number of ways you can choose a single "box" to contain the symbol 0 and another to contain the symbol 1? Can a box contain just one symbol, or both, or neither?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.  It belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: No it's not about Maths because I want to know the result by programming. Each boxes can be feel by 0 or 1, that's it.

Comment: `def f(): return 2 ** 25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def combinations(S,K):
    return S**K;
```

Comment: I wanted to effectively fill the arrays, and add 1 to a counter for each array. But seeing the comment, it shouldn't be a good idea... Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 25 bits here, your answer is 2^25 = 33554432